# Angular: measuring buttons and setting property after they are drawn

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a scenario where I am displaying a series of buttons. If the screen is not large enough for the buttons, I display a combobox.

The template code of interest:

```
<div *ngIf="useDropdown" ngbDropdown>drop down code...</div>
<button *ngFor='let btn of buttons'>{{btn.title}}</button>
```

The component code of interest:

```
public useDropdown:boolean;

ngAfterViewInit() {       
  this.useDropdown = this.isDropdownNeeded();//returns a boolean 
}
```

So the idea is that once the buttons are drawn on the screen, I measure (in the isDropdownNeeded method) if there is enough space for the buttons. Then return a boolean which is bound to an ngIf to show or hide a combobox. The isDropdownNeeded() also removes the buttons if that is the case.

Problem is that I am getting `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`. This is caused by the code updating useDropdown's value before the current cycle finishes.

I tried using setTimeOut, which makes the buttons display for a brief moment and flicker off before showing the combobox. Not visually elegant...

I then tried:

```
ngAfterContentChecked() {
    this.useDropdown = this.isDropdownNeeded();
}
```

This works but it is called all the time. I can put a mechanism to at least stop isDropdownNeeded() to get called all the time, but parts of the application get data updates often and this can get expensive...

I found a few ways to fake ngFor event once it is done drawing, but none of them really worked.

So, how can I measure a bunch of buttons width after they are drawn in order to set a template property without getting `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`?

Comment: Try converting your userDropdown to an subject (startWith(false) )and then in your afterViewinit do this.useDropdown.next(this.isDropDownNeeded()). The condition will change to `*ngIf="useDropdown | async"`

Comment: Interesting idea thanks. But this seems to have same effect as if I were to initially declare the bool useDropdown to false. When we load the page in desktop screen all is fine, but when I load from small screen still and error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '[object Object]'. Current value: 'true'.